# how to add a new paypal sdk to file autoload.php of another paypal sdk that already exist in php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i already installed adaptivepayments-sdk-php in my project and it have own file autoload.php and directory composer. composer directory have these following files : autoload_classmap.php,autoload_namespaces.php,autoload_psr4.php,autoload_real.php,ClassLoader.php and also a json file installed.json.

now i want to add a new sdk adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php in project and also want both sdk should have same file autoload.php.

so please guide me how to do it.
Note:- i already downloaded zip file of adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php

Answer (score 1):

since you already have a composer.json, open it and add this

```
"autoload":{
   "psr-4":{
       "namespace\\to\\root\\of\\sdk":"path/to/root/of/sdk"
       "namespace\\to\\root\\of\\sdk2":"path/to/root/of/sdk2"
   }
}
```

Run `composer update`after that